# Removing items from listbox according to their values VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I'm trying to delete all the items in a user form list-box except for specific values

lets say I want to delete everything in my list-box except "Cat" and "Dog"

I wrote:

```
For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.List(i) <> "Cat" or ListBox2.List(i) <> "Dog" Then
        ListBox2.RemoveItem i
    End If
Next
```

For some reason it doesn't work, I tried to find a solution but I couldn't.
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use backwards loop:

```
For i = ListBox2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox2.List(i) <> "Cat" AND ListBox2.List(i) <> "Dog" Then
        ListBox2.RemoveItem i
    End If
Next
```

and also change `OR` to `AND` in your `IF` statement