# Removing items in a loop error - Could not get the selected property

Tags: vba, listbox, powerpoint

Following is the code for a userform listbox:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim i%
'ListBox2.Clear
For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.Selected(i) = True Then
        ListBox2.RemoveItem (i)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I get the error:

> Could not get the selected property. Invalid argument.

It highlights the line

```
If ListBox2.Selected(i) = True Then
```

Its strange since the following code works:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i%
'ListBox2.Clear
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
        ListBox2.AddItem ListBox1.List(i)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code might be trying to select the item it just deleted. What if you reverse the For Next loop? Like so:
For i = listbox1.listcount to 0 step -1
''''""""
Next

Comment: Also check the answer to this question for a clearer example of a reverse/backwards loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215035/removing-items-from-listbox-according-to-their-values-vba